# JOINING Same Table gives duplicate information

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I want to join the same table to get some information.

I have a **Person Table**

```
PersonId, FirstName, LastName, Address
```

Also **Patient Table**

> PatientId, PersonId, ResponsiblePersonId

Below is the query i tried to get Patient's FirstName, Last Name also the Responsible Person FirstName, Last Name. For this I JOINED Person table once again to get Responsible Persons First, Last names.

**But I got many duplicate records.**

```
SELECT   PAT.PatientId

        ,PER.PersonNumber
        ,PER.FirstName
        ,PER.LastName
        ,RES_PER.FirstName AS ResFirstName
        ,RES_PER.LastName AS ResLastName
        ,PER.Address                

FROM        dbo.Patient AS PAT
INNER JOIN  dbo.Person AS PER
    ON  PAT.PersonId = PER.PersonId
INNER JOIN  dbo.Person AS RES_PER
    ON  PAT.ResponsiblePersonId = PER.PersonId
```

How can i get Patient FirstName, LastName & Responsible Person's First Name, Last Name for the patient record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to join table `Person` twice on table `Patient` in order to get the two dependent columns on it.

```
SELECT  b.FirstName Patient_FirstName, 
        b.LastName Patient_LastName,  
        b.Address Patient_Address,
        c.FirstName Responsible_Firstname, 
        c.LastName Responsible_LastName, 
        c.Address Responsible_Address
FROM    Patient a
        INNER JOIN Person b
            ON a.PersonID = b.PersonID
        INNER JOIN Person c
            ON a.ResponsiblePersonId = c.PersonID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: I tried that already. But SOF says ' You can accept an answer in 8 Minutes' Now 4 minutes. Will accept and make sure this question got answer :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is replace `PER` with `RES_PER` in the very last bit of your SQL. (i.e. PER.PersonId becomes RES_PER.PersonId).

```
SELECT   PAT.PatientId
        ,PER.PersonNumber
        ,PER.FirstName
        ,PER.LastName
        ,RES_PER.FirstName AS ResFirstName
        ,RES_PER.LastName AS ResLastName
        ,PER.Address                

FROM        dbo.Patient AS PAT
INNER JOIN  dbo.Person AS PER
    ON  PAT.PersonId = PER.PersonId
INNER JOIN  dbo.Person AS RES_PER
    ON  PAT.ResponsiblePersonId = RES_PER.PersonId
```